# SignalR asp.net sending request to the hub

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have this hub:

```
public class NoteHub : Hub
    {
        public void  BroadcastNotificationToSpecificPage()
        {
            Clients.All.broadcastNotificationToSpecificPage();
        }
    }
```

This in on the client part:

```
 $(function () {
             var noteHub = $.connection.noteHub;

             noteHub.client.broadcastNotificationToSpecificPage = function () {
                 ShowSignalRPopup();
                 console.log("TEST");
                 noteHub.server.broadcastNotificationToSpecificPage()
             };

             $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                 console.log("SignalR connected.");
             }).fail(function (error) {
                 console.error("SignalR connection error: " + error);
             });
         })
```

and I have a button and when is press I want send the request to the

> NoteHub -> BroadcastNotificationToSpecificPage

where I can manipulate data and after broadcast to clients.

```
 protected void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
               

                var notehub= GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NoteHub>();
                notehub.Clients.All.broadcastNotificationToSpecificPage();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OrderLineNotesLabel.Text = ex.Message;
            }
```

Right now when I click the button the client is notified but this happens directly from InsertButton_Click and I want first to go to the hub and after to go to the cliets. How can I do this?

Thank you!